# Should we include max_bars_back inside function or in out scope?

Tags: pine-script

For example, we have:

```
myVar = close + xyz
max_bars_back(myVar, 5000) // <----- is this correct place ?
myF()=>
    ...
    max_bars_back(myVar, 5000) // <----- is this correct place ?
    cond = myVar[4444]
```

which one is correct place if we access myVar only in funcion?

Answer (score 0):

The max_bars_back is an argument for entire script and should be included only in the study() or strategy() functions.

```
study("My script", max_bars_back = 5000)
strategy("My strategy", max_bars_back = 5000)
```